# Connect VBA to MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I know it has been asked many times, but none of them helped in my case.

so here is piece of code:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection

Sub Macro1()

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};" _
& "SERVER=server;" _
& "DATABASE=DB;" _
& "UID=USER;PWD=PW; OPTION=3"

oConn.Open
```

[image]

[image]

what could be wrong?

Comment: I think the format of your connection string is wrong.  I don't have MySQL installed to test.  But takle a look at the excellent [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/).

Comment: Can you try like this: `MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver` in the connection string. Or the best case is simply to install this and work: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/